# Is it possible to show 2 url page details in home page component one below another?

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

I have a situation where i need to use two show 2 URL pages and show the details in home page. Is it possible? When i try to do that with the below visualforce page only either one of the url details is being shown.

```
<apex:page>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:50%">
                <iframe src="https://cs13.salesforce.com/003?fcf=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
                    width="100%"  
                    height="100"/>
            </td>
            <td style="width:50%">
                <iframe src="https://cs13.salesforce.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
                    width="100%" 
                    height="100"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is "https://cs13.salesforce.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx" valid url? Inspect the page and check if you get any javascript error in console

Comment: @Reshma I just specified an example URL in the code i posted. It is not the actual URL.

Comment: @Reshma When I navigate to home page either one of the URL details is viewable but i want both of them to be viewable.

Comment: I understood that url is not actual one. Just want to clear that if you paste in browser will it show corresponding page or something. One more thing, when you preview the vf page can you see both url details?

Comment: @Reshma Yes. When i paste both the url separately in browser it shows the corresponding page. When i preview the vf page no data is shown but i have added the vf page as a component in home page and when i view the home page either one of the url details is being shown.

Comment: Tried in my dev org, it is working fine. Do you see any errors in Console?

Comment: @RahulSharma I don't see any errors in the console but when i go to the home page either the first url or second url data is getting populated. When i click the home tab multiple times i see the details being changed to url 1 or url 2 details. Both the details are not shown simultaneously.

Comment: @RahulSharma when the home tab is clicked either one of the url which i used is replacing the home page url.

Comment: no luck, unable to reproduce

Comment: @RahulSharma I have created a visualforce page and used the code that i posted and created a home page component with it and then added it to the home page layout. Then when i go to the home page i get this issue. Did you try the same scenario?

Comment: @RahulSharma Just a quick question. Does using url in iframe tag will replace main url?

Comment: In your code, you've specified the width of each cell to 50% without allowing any float for borders, etc. You've not specified any CSS that says 'noborder' or 'invisible' (or whatever the setting is). What happens if you do something like that or set the width of each cell to 48%? I'm not certain that you want to set the height of the I frame to 100%. I think this all CSS and formatting issue.

Comment: @Ean, it should not replace iframe URL, added the steps and output which i tried in my DEV org.